# Showing a function has a global minimum

Tags: analysis, functions

Find a function $f:\mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R $, so that  $f´(x)\cdot x \geq 0 \quad\forall x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Let $f(x_i) = x_i^2 \Longrightarrow f´(x_i)= 2x_i \Longrightarrow 2x_i \cdot x_i =2x_i^2 \geq 0 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Now show that all functions with that property have a global minimum in $0$.

I tried to use a function $g(t) = f(tx)$ with $t\in \mathbb R \quad$ but didnt get far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the right idea though, $g'(t)=\nabla f(tx)\cdot x=\frac1t\nabla f(tx)\cdot tx\ge 0$ for $t> 0$, so $g$ is increasing in $[0,\infty]$. In particular, $g(1)=f(x)\ge g(0)=f(0)$.

Comment: Oh thats very smart thank you alot